# Android App Crashes on Deleting child node From Firebase Android in Image Slider

Tags: android, firebase

Here, I have successfully added a Realtime Firebase Database Image Slider which Retrieves images and shows them in an image slider. Everything's working fine. All updation of images and all. Except when I'm deleting the child node in my Firebase realtime database the app crashes.

**Home Fragment**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


DatabaseReference databaseReference;
List<ImageSliderModel> slideLists;

SliderView sliderView;
int TotalCounts;

public HomeFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    slideLists = new ArrayList<>();

    sliderView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageSlider);


    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ImagesLinks").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot != null) {
                Long counts = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                TotalCounts = counts.intValue();

                sliderView.setSliderAdapter(new ImageSliderAdapter(getActivity(), TotalCounts));
                sliderView.setIndicatorAnimation(IndicatorAnimations.WORM);
                sliderView.setSliderTransformAnimation(SliderAnimations.SIMPLETRANSFORMATION);
                sliderView.setAutoCycleDirection(SliderView.AUTO_CYCLE_DIRECTION_BACK_AND_FORTH);
                sliderView.setIndicatorSelectedColor(Color.WHITE);
                sliderView.setIndicatorUnselectedColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                sliderView.setScrollTimeInSec(3);
                sliderView.startAutoCycle();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
     return view;
   }
}
```

**XML CODE**

```
    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewflipper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoStart="true"
        android:flipInterval="2000">

        <com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderView
            android:id="@+id/imageSlider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:sliderAutoCycleDirection="back_and_forth"
            app:sliderIndicatorAnimationDuration="600"
            app:sliderIndicatorGravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            app:sliderIndicatorSelectedColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            app:sliderIndicatorUnselectedColor="#FFCCCCCC"
            app:sliderScrollTimeInSec="3"
            app:sliderStartAutoCycle="true" />
    </ViewFlipper>
```

**Image Slider Adapter**

```
public class ImageSliderAdapter extends SliderViewAdapter<SliderviewHolder> {

Context context;
int setTotalCount;
String ImageLink;

public ImageSliderAdapter(Context context, int setTotalCount) {
    this.setTotalCount = setTotalCount;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public SliderviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.slider_item_layout,parent,false);
    return new SliderviewHolder(view) ;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SliderviewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ImagesLinks").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    ImageLink = dataSnapshot.child("1").getValue().toString();
                    Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView).load(ImageLink).into(viewHolder.sliderImageview);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    ImageLink = dataSnapshot.child("2").getValue().toString();
                    Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView).load(ImageLink).into(viewHolder.sliderImageview);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    ImageLink = dataSnapshot.child("3").getValue().toString();
                    Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView).load(ImageLink).into(viewHolder.sliderImageview);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    ImageLink = dataSnapshot.child("4").getValue().toString();
                    Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView).load(ImageLink).into(viewHolder.sliderImageview);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    ImageLink = dataSnapshot.child("5").getValue().toString();
                    Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView).load(ImageLink).into(viewHolder.sliderImageview);
                    break;

                case 5:
                    ImageLink = dataSnapshot.child("6").getValue().toString();
                    Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView).load(ImageLink).into(viewHolder.sliderImageview);
                    break;

                case 6:
                    ImageLink = dataSnapshot.child("7").getValue().toString();
                    Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView).load(ImageLink).into(viewHolder.sliderImageview);
                    break;

                case 7:
                    ImageLink = dataSnapshot.child("8").getValue().toString();
                    Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView).load(ImageLink).into(viewHolder.sliderImageview);
                    break;

                case 8:
                    ImageLink = dataSnapshot.child("9").getValue().toString();
                    Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView).load(ImageLink).into(viewHolder.sliderImageview);
                    break;

                case 9:
                    ImageLink = dataSnapshot.child("10").getValue().toString();
                    Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView).load(ImageLink).into(viewHolder.sliderImageview);
                    break;

                default:
                    return;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
  }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return setTotalCount;
   }
}

class SliderviewHolder extends SliderViewAdapter.ViewHolder {
ImageView sliderImageview;
View itemView;
public SliderviewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    this.itemView = itemView;
    sliderImageview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview02);
  }
}
```

**Image Slider Model**

```
public class ImageSliderModel {

String imageUrl;

public ImageSliderModel() {
}

public ImageSliderModel(String imageUrl){
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
  }
 }
```

This is all with the source code. Note: All values in the firebase root child are updating correctly, except child from root node deleting.

here's Crash Log Report

```
enter code here
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.demo.test, PID: 30101
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference         
at com.demo.test.HomePage.ImageSliderAdapter$1.onDataChange(ImageSliderAdapter.java:50)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegf.zza(Unknown Source:13)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source:2)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source:71)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
 Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

**Firebase Model**

[image]

Comment: please upload crash log from logcat

Comment: Likely the `sliderView`  ...

Comment: @NensiKasundra updated the crash log please have a look at it.

Comment: When you call `dataSnapshot.child("X").getValue()`, are you sure there are images available after you have deleted a particular child node? I think when your deleting a child node, that data is no longer accessible and when you try to access it with hardcoded path, it will return `null` value, causing this error.

Comment: Yes... When I deleted a particular child there's no data to be fetched. You are right! @VivekSasidharan Please help me find a solution.

Comment: So, don't access the child nodes in a hardcoded manner! You have to consider the case where either one of the hard-coded paths is no longer available or total number of child nodes is less than 10. Can't you try iterating using `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` instead of `switch` statement?

Comment: Please help me out with the code. @VivekSasidharan I am new to android, and still learning things... Can you tell me that how to iterate using dataSnapshot.getChildren() instead of switch?

Comment: @VivekSasidharan please help me out with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `ImageSliderAdapter.java` file, when you call `dataSnapshot.child("X").getValue()`, since "X" is hardcoded, it might return `null` after you have deleted the child node. So, for this to work, please update `ImageSliderAdapter.java` as follows:

**ImageSliderAdapter.java**

```
public class ImageSliderAdapter extends SliderViewAdapter < SliderviewHolder > {

 Context context;
 List<String> slideLists;

 public ImageSliderAdapter(Context context, List<String> slideLists) {
  this.slideLists = slideLists;
  this.context = context;
 }

 @Override
 public SliderviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
  View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.slider_item_layout, parent, false);
  return new SliderviewHolder(view);
 }

 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(final SliderviewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    String imageUrl = slideLists.get(position); 
  Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView).load(imageUrl).into(viewHolder.sliderImageview);
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  return slideLists.size();
 }
}

class SliderviewHolder extends SliderViewAdapter.ViewHolder {
 ImageView sliderImageview;
 View itemView;

 public SliderviewHolder(View itemView) {
  super(itemView);
  this.itemView = itemView;
  sliderImageview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview02);
 }
}
```

And update the `HomeFragment.java` as follows. I am converting the child node data to string and passing it as a list to the adapter. Because calling `addValueEventListener()` inside `onBindViewHolder()` is not a good idea since it will create multiple listeners which is not required in this context.

**HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


DatabaseReference databaseReference;
List<String> slideLists;

SliderView sliderView;
int TotalCounts;

public HomeFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    slideLists = new ArrayList<>();

    sliderView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageSlider);


    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ImagesLinks").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                slideLists.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String model = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                    slideLists.add(model);
                }
                sliderView.setSliderAdapter(new ImageSliderAdapter(getActivity(), slideLists));
                sliderView.setIndicatorAnimation(IndicatorAnimations.WORM);
                sliderView.setSliderTransformAnimation(SliderAnimations.SIMPLETRANSFORMATION);
                sliderView.setAutoCycleDirection(SliderView.AUTO_CYCLE_DIRECTION_BACK_AND_FORTH);
                sliderView.setIndicatorSelectedColor(Color.WHITE);
                sliderView.setIndicatorUnselectedColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                sliderView.setScrollTimeInSec(3);
                sliderView.startAutoCycle();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
     return view;
   }
}
```

Comment: sorry for bothering you again. But can you show me how to store data in the child node as per the model covered by ImageSliderModel.java. please it will be a great help!

Comment: Can you edit the question to include some sample representation of data in firebase?

Comment: Yes! I tried it. But as soon as I open it again whole app crashes

Comment: Please try now. I have changed from using `ImageSliderModel.java` to `String` as in your older code. Let me know if that works!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211701/discussion-between-abhishek-dharmik-and-vivek-sasidharan).